# Unable to get desire response from fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

I was using an fake_api to display simple things on my local network. I am using express node.js framework for this.

`app.get('/getEntry/:key', (req, res) => { res.send(getEntry(req.params.key)) return getEntry(req.params.key) })`

This should only display some dummy value and it display what I expect on the chrome browser.

[screenshot for web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2YTF.png)

However, when I fetch it I can not get my desired response, which is a string that is "Val is val1"

Updated code:

```
fetch(`http://${local_IP}:3000/getEntry/${hash}`,{
    Method: 'POST',
    Headers: {
      Accept: 'application.json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    Cache: 'default'
  })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return (response.blob())
        } else {
          throw new Error('Error: ' + response.status);
        }
      })
      .then(blob => {
        console.log(blob)
        console.log(2)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        console.log(3)
      });

    }
```

After making adjustment as slebetman suggested now this the code above that is updated the log is this

```json
{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "20D4D114-423D-496A-B5F5-2DF02B644B8A", "name": "Asfa.html", "offset": 0, "size": 11, "type": "text/html"}}
```

So now I have the blob element but I still did not have the desire return which is just the string "Val is val1"

The response variable is:

```json
{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "EC917970-CAB9-4ED1-B7BE-3DD65128C294", "name": "Asfa.html", "offset": 0, "size": 11, "type": "text/html"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "EC917970-CAB9-4ED1-B7BE-3DD65128C294", "name": "Asfa.html", "offset": 0, "size": 11, "type": "text/html"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"connection": "keep-alive", "content-length": "11", "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "date": "Thu, 22 Jun 2023 21:22:19 GMT", "etag": "W/\"b-PP2DhlNqgm5t6T/UuubuFEzI4JU\"", "keep-alive": "timeout=5", "x-powered-by": "Express"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "http://${local_IP}:3000/getEntry/Asfa"}
```

I try to use many different method such as text(), blob(), json() to process the response and none of them worked. I believe it is blob formatted but then the blob variable is undefined

Comment: It's undefined because you're not returning anything. The default value you get when you return nothing is `undefined`. Logging on the console does not cause something to be returned. You need to do `return response.blob()` (or `text()`) instead of `setReturnVal(response)`. Then in the next `.then()` you can do `setReturnVal(blob)`

Comment: After trying slebetman suggested when I try to read the blob variable it gives me an error stating "[TypeError: Already read]"

Comment: Return it. Don't console.log it

Comment: The `fetch()` options properties are `method`, `headers` and `cache`, all lowercase. Why are you trying to send a POST request though? Why are you interpreting the response as a Blob?

Comment: To Phil is on strike, for the options I do not think it influence the return. And the reason I interpret the response as a Blob is because for the response it have a blobId. However, I am not sure what is the correct way to interpret the response and text() return something even make less sense.

Comment: To slebetman, would directly use the blob to save as a variable or return it make the value change? Would it be the same as console.log()?

Answer (score 0):

Just return the call to `response.*`:

```js
fetch( URL, options )
.then(response => {
  return response.blob() // <-- Return the result of response.blob() so that it's available on the next then() as its first parameter ('blob')
})
.then(blob => {
  console.log(blob) // <-- result of response.blob() is available here
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
  console.log(3)
});
```

Of course, you can parse the response in any way you want:

```js
return response.text()
return response.json()
```

*Note:* the call to `response.*` can only happen once (it's a stream that's read once) that's why you cannot `console.log` it and return it at the same time, hence the error `Already read`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, I tried that and with the blob element I still couldn't get the result I desired.

Comment: Try with response.text() and (debug) see what comes up. Otherwise, check the catch() error log for more information, in case there's an error thrown.